# First and second Observer subscribe handler

Tags: websocket, rxjs, subject

I have code like this:

```
const i = 0;
const subject = webSocket(WEBSOCKET_API_URL);

subject.subscribe(
  msg => {
    if(i===0) {
      firstHandler();
    }
    if(i===1) {
      secondHandler();
    }
    else {
      globalHanlder();
    }
    if(i <= 2) { 
      i++;
    }
  }
);

subject.next({
  event: "testSubscribe",
});
```

I want to subscribe to a WebSocket channel, send a message, and handle 2 first responses differently than other ones.

I did it as you can see above.
I don't like the solution.
And I'm wondering if there is some prettier way of doing it for handling first, and second function call with rxjs usage.

Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd do it almost the same way you did it. Maybe I would rather let the `i` variable be defined inside the chain. Maybe if you don't need the values emitted by `subject` you can replace them with indices.

```
subject.pipe(
  map((value, index) => index),
).subscribe(index => {
  if (index === 0) {
    firstHandler();
  } else if (index === 1) {
    secondHandler();
  } else {
    globalHanlder();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is fine. Not neccessary cleaner with Observable operator but following will do the same thing

```
const 1st=subject.pipe(take(2),last(),tap(()=>firstHandler()))
const 2nd=subject.pipe(first(),tap(()=>secondHandler()))
const other=subject.pipe(skip(2),tap(()=>globalHandler()))
merge(1st,2nd,other).subscribe()
```